# Creating a trigger that grants a role to every new created user

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a problem with creating a trigger that grants a role each time I create a new user how can I do it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER  grant_role_to_user
AFTER  insert ON "here I need the right table" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    GRANT role_1 to : NEW.USERNAME
END;
/
```

I tried the table all_users, dba_users; but it gives me an error "can't create a trigger on this view"

using oracle 10g

Comment: onew way you can do is  create a procedure which you will call if you need to grant the grants to the user, in the procedure execute the create user and then execute the Grant's to the role.

Comment: What you want is a system trigger, which would be `on database`. However I'm not sure any of the [supplied DDL events](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#sthref7935) capture creation of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Include `GRANT ROLE` into a script you use to create new users, i.e.

```
create user        mike     identified by lion;
grant role_1 to    mike;
```

Comment: i see, yeah that works too, but is there any way i can do it using triggers ? or it can't be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need `trigger` for it.

Just assign this `role` to `public` and every user will have this role assigned.(including user that will be created in the future). But be aware about what you are doing. You really mean it.

```
grant role_1 to public;
```